# Having trouble with Interactive Plane

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, 3d, papervision3d

I am having some trouble getting an interactive, animated plane created from a MovieClip in the Library to show any kind of animation or receive any mouse events.

Specifically, I am having issues with the different states of Button instances in the MovieClip.

Here's the basic code that I am testing with:

```
    private function init3D():void
    {
        viewport = new Viewport3D(1024, 768, false, true);
        addChild(viewport);

        camera = new Camera3D();
        camera.z = -500;
        camera.zoom = 1;
        camera.focus = 500;
        camera.target = DisplayObject3D.ZERO;

        scene = new Scene3D();
        renderer = new BasicRenderEngine();

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }

    public function addChild3D(link:String):Plane
    {
        //var demoPlane:DemoPlane = new DemoPlane(link);
        //return scene.addChild(demoPlane.getPlane());

        var material:MovieAssetMaterial = new MovieAssetMaterial(link, false, true, false, false);
        material.interactive = true;
        //material.smooth = true;
        material.animated = true;

        var plane_mc:Plane = new Plane(material, 0, 0, 10, 10);
        scene.addChild(plane_mc);

    }

    private function loop(evt:Event):void
    {
        renderer.renderScene(scene, camera, viewport);
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I see no handler for any buttons in the code.

Comment: The handlers are inside of the MovieClip which I'm adding with addChild3D:
start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startDemo);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update VirtualMouse class with patch to handle SimpleButton

http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/issues/detail?id=169

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried you code

```
package{

    import org.papervision3d.*;
    import org.papervision3d.view.*;
    import org.papervision3d.cameras.*;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.*;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.*;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.*;
    import org.papervision3d.scenes.*;
    import org.papervision3d.render.*;

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class PV3DPlane extends MovieClip{

        private var viewport:Viewport3D;
        private var camera:Camera3D;
        private var scene:Scene3D;
        private var renderer:BasicRenderEngine;
        private var plane:Plane;

        public function PV3DPlane(){
            init3D();
        }

        private function init3D():void
        {
                viewport = new Viewport3D(1024, 768, false, true);
                addChild(viewport);

                camera = new Camera3D();
                camera.z = -500;
                camera.zoom = 1;
                camera.focus = 500;
                camera.target = DisplayObject3D.ZERO;

                scene = new Scene3D();
                renderer = new BasicRenderEngine();


                plane = addChild3D('asset');

                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        public function addChild3D(link:String):Plane
        {
                var material:MovieAssetMaterial = new MovieAssetMaterial(link, false, true, false, false);
                material.interactive = true;
                //material.smooth = true;
                material.animated = true;
                material.doubleSided = true;

                var plane_mc:Plane = new Plane(material, 0, 0, 10, 10);
                scene.addChild(plane_mc);
                return plane_mc;
        }

        private function loop(evt:Event):void
        {
                plane.rotationY++;
                renderer.renderScene(scene, camera, viewport);
        }
    }
}
```

I works fine for me...I just created a dummy clip named *button* and added:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(){trace('click')});
```

I get the trace, all works fine.
What papervision build are you using ?
On this machine I have an older one
Papervision3D Public Beta 2.0 - Great White (20.08.25)

here is the [fla](http://www.lifesine.eu/so/plane/PV3DPlane.fla) and the [as](http://www.lifesine.eu/so/plane/PV3DPlane.as) file I used.

Comment: I think the problem is that I am trying to use SimpleButtons and those aren't supported by PV3D.